# Pythonize Javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, python

I am working on my bachelors work, and I am building something like interpreter. I want to convert the Javascript code into Python. I came to a point that I want to convert For Loop into Python which looks like this:

```
for(var x = 0; x < some_length; x++) {
}
```

in python it would look like this:

```
for x in range(0, some_length):
```

the problem is I want to cover all the cases that can happen, like for example going backwards like this:

```
for(var x = some_length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
}
```

can somebody help me to write a function that will transpile this into python?

**IMPORTANT EDIT!!!**

as input to the function that will transpile the for loop into python are:

```
 function pythonize(firstAction, condition, action)
```

where

```
firstAction = "x = 0",

condition = "x < some_length"

action = "x++"
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be like, you can check [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function for more of its detailed usage:

```
for x in range(some_length - 1, -1, -1):
```

Notice I change the step from `x++` to decrement, otherwise the for loop won't terminate.

Answer (score 1):

`range` accepts `start, end, step`, so you can do

```
for x in range(some_length-1, -1, -1)
```

Another option is

```
for x in reversed(range(some_length))
```

note: I assume you mean `x--` in your second example

Answer (score 0):

I've created this long function to transpile javascript for loop into python for loop:

```
function pyt(c) {
  var cc = c.split('(')[1];
  cc = cc.substr(0,cc.length-1);
  pp = cc.split(';');
  var r1 = /[A-Za-z\$\_]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\_]* ?= ?(.*)/.exec(pp[0])[1];
  var r2 = '';
  if(pp[1].indexOf('<') > -1) {
    r2 = /[A-Za-z\$\_]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\_]* ?<=? ?(.*)/.exec(pp[1])[1]
  } else if(pp[1].indexOf('>') > -1) {
    r2 = /[A-Za-z\$\_]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\_]* ?>=? ?(.*)/.exec(pp[1])[1]
  }
  var delta = 0;
  if(pp[1].indexOf('>=')) {
    delta = -1;
    }
  if(pp[1].indexOf('<=')) {
    delta = 1;
  }
  var e2 = 0;
  if(!isNaN(r2)) {
     e2 = Number(r2) + delta;
  } else {
    if(delta !== 0) {
        e2 = r2 + (delta > 0 ? '+' : '-') + delta;
    } else {
        e2 = r2;
    }
  }

  var r3 = '';
  if(/[A-Za-z\$\_]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\_]*\+\+/.test(pp[2])) {
    r3 = '1';
  } else if(/[A-Za-z\$\_]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\_]*\-\-/.test(pp[2])) {
    r3 = '-1';
  } else {
    if(pp[2].indexOf('+=') > -1) {
        r3 = /[A-Za-z\$\_]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\_]* ?\+= ?(.*)/.exec(pp[2])[1];
    } else if(pp[2].indexOf('-=') > -1) {
        r3 = /[A-Za-z\$\_]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\_]* ?\-= ?(.*)/.exec(pp[2])[1];
    } else {
        if(/([A-Za-z\$\_]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\_]*) ?= ?\1 ?\+ ?(.*)/.test(pp[2])) {
            r3 = /([A-Za-z\$\_]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\_]*) ?= ?\1 ?\+ ?(.*)/.exec(pp[2])[2];
      } else {
        r3 = /([A-Za-z\$\_]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\_]*) ?= ?\1 ?\- ?(.*)/.exec(pp[2])[2];
      }
    }
  }
  p = 'for i in range(' + r1 + ', ' + e2 + ', ' + r3 + ')';
  return p;
}

var c = "for(i = 30 + y;i>=10 - 1; i = i + 0.1)";
console.log(pyt(c));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x7uhxbua/12/

It's basically using regex to do the magic. It covers most of the cases, but not all.